# python: sort list with multiple values

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of CrewRecords objects.

```
crew_record = list[<CrewRecords instance at 0x617bb48>, 
                   <CrewRecords instance at 0x617b9e0>,
                   <CrewRecords instance at 0x5755680>]
```

where:

```
class CrewRecords():
    def __init__(self):
        self.crew_id                = None
        self.crew_date_of_hire      = None       
        self.crew_points            = None
    def crew_attributes(self,crew_bag):
        ''' populate the values of crew with some values'''
        self.crew_id                = crew_bag.crew.id()
        self.crew_date_of_hire      = crew_bag.crew.date_of_hire()
        self.crew_points            = crew_bag.crew_points()
```

Now, i want to write a function in python which takes 3 arguments and sort the list by the preferences provided. i.e.

if the user inputs the value to be sort by 
options:

1. points, date_of_hire, id
2. points, id, date_of_hire
3. date_of_hire, points, id
   etc.. sort based on user input.

then, function should be able to sort with sort.i.e.
if the 1st option is chosen, then sort all crew by points, if 2 crew has same points then sort by date_of_hire, if date_of_hire is also same then sort by id.

Also, later if the sort options increases like if the user wants to sort by some extra option (by name for example) we should also be able to easily extend the sort criteria.

Comment: You need to show what you've tried and where you're stuck, etc. Can't just expect others to do the work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `key` keyword to `sorted`, i.e.

```
return sorted(crew_record, key=attrgetter('crew_points', 'crew_date_of_hire', 'crew_id'))
```

would solve your first point.